# Equal height of navigation and logo with vertical text alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a simple nav I'm trying to recreate and I have got to the right section and I have gotten stuck with the li's, the li that is orange is not filling the 100% and I need the links to not center but align middle. an example of what I am trying to accomplish

Here's a [page example](http://www.blacksquad.com/) of what I am trying to achieve. And a screenshot:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```css
.page-header{
 display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 110;
 background-color: aqua;
}
.header-standard { 
 height: 86px; 
}
.branding{
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
.branding img {
 height: 60px;
 margin: 15px 25px;
}
.standard-nav{
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
 float: right;
}
.special-link {
 display: inline;
    background-color: #ff5252;
    width: 200px;
 height: auto;
    text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
}
.standard-nav > ul > li {    
 bottom: 0;
}
.standard-nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  <div class="header-standard">
  <div class="branding">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <nav class="standard-nav">
   <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
    <li class="special-link">Special Link</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
   
  </div>
</header>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this layout using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of float.

```css
.page-header {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 110;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.header-standard {
  height: 86px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.branding img {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 15px 25px;
}

.standard-nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.standard-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.special-link {
  background-color: #ff5252;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.standard-nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  <div class="header-standard">
    <div class="branding">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <nav class="standard-nav">
      <ul>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 4</li>
        <li class="special-link">Special Link</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of flex. Of course, you will need to add prefixes depending on the browsers you support.

HTML

```
<header class="page-header header-standard">

    <div class="branding">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>

    <nav class="standard-nav">
      <ul>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 4</li>
        <li class="special-link">Special Link</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
```

CSS

```
header,
nav,
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

nav li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

---

Here's a JsFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/0xz5of71/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need add `height: 100%; margin: 0; line-height: 86px` to `ul` and fix the height of left element because it expands over height of parent.

```css
.page-header{
 display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 110;
 background-color: aqua;
}
.header-standard { 
 height: 86px; 
}
.branding{
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
.branding img {
 height: 60px;
 margin: 15px 25px;
}
.standard-nav{
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
 float: right;
}
.special-link {
 display: inline;
    background-color: #ff5252;
    width: 200px;
 height: auto;
    text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
}
.standard-nav > ul > li {    
 bottom: 0;
}
.standard-nav > ul {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 86px;
  height: 100%:
}
.standard-nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  <div class="header-standard">
  <div class="branding">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <nav class="standard-nav">
   <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
    <li class="special-link">Special Link</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
   
  </div>
</header>​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only float the logo, then text-align the nav without floatting works too.

else `display:table/flex/grid` to avoid float are also options.

```css
.page-header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.header-standard {}

body{margin:0;}

.branding {
  float: left;
}

.branding img {
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.standard-nav {
  text-align: right;
}

.special-link {
  background-color: #ff5252;
}

.standard-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.standard-nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 0.5em
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  <div class="header-standard">
    <div class="branding">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <nav class="standard-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a class="special-link" href="#">Special Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>​
```